# container.setLeadComponent(...) in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

This question is mostly theoretical. In the manual of Codename One, I've read the section about "Lead Component":
https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html#lead-component-section

It seems that the (only?) "leader" component of a `Container` that makes sense is a `Button`. Are there other cases to choose a leader component that is not a `Button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by far the most common but I've seen developers use a `TextArea` as a lead and it worked. You can also use other button subclasses such as `CheckBox`, `RadioButton` etc.

Comment: activating the lead component can affect the scroll block in a Container BoxLayout Y?

Comment: Scrolling doesn't work within a lead component.

Comment: scrolling not inside where I use leadComponent but if I have a paret Container with scrolling yes

Comment: don't worry I could found the problem. Never use 2 or more Button inside a Container with lead component because the Parent Container fail in Scrolling in that item that have Lead component enable in it container.

Comment: I don't understand the question.